# Adding Prepared Maps causes Android SDK to crash

Tags: android, skmaps

I am using the Skobbler Android SDK within a cordova plugin. It works fine in ONLINE Mode, showing me the map view. But my goal is to provide maps for OFFLINE navigation. So I followed the following tutorial on prepared maps:

http://sdkblog.skobbler.com/creating-an-app-with-a-pre-bundled-map/

But now in OFFLINE MODE with having added the map files of my area to the SKMaps.zip when trying to display the map view the app crashes with the following error:

libc - Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000044 (code=1)

Any idea what to do here and make it work?

Is there a better tutorial on how to work with prepared maps?

Comment: Have you checked the "managing prebundled map packages" chapter from the website: http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec025?

Comment: Ah OK the part about the needed "Meta Files" was missing in the example on the developer blog. Now its working. Thanks.

Comment: Hello Rotzoll, I'm ionic developer and i want to render same Skobbler map for android platform. so any native android side coding are required?. or only cordova plugin fix rendering map? please give me example how you are loading map.

Comment: Hello, I'm hybrid application developer and i want to use skobbler map in my ionic project so please tell me which one cordova plugin you are using for that.

Answer (score 2):

The SDK requires some meta files in order to be able to render the map.

SKMetaDataListener provides a callback ( public void onMetaDataDownloadFinished(int versionNumber) ) that tells you when these meta files are ready. Only after receiving this callback the map can be successfully rendered. 
See: http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec022a

Comment: Hi sylvia, please help me how to Skobble map render using cross platform. i had installed plugin successfully but I'm not able to loading map.

Comment: Hello, I'm hybrid application developer and i want to use skobbler map in my ionic project so please tell me which one cordova plugin you are using for that.